# Codignator does not bind the array values

Tags: html, css, arrays

I am trying to create a registration form for my website that time I am trying to push the data to the database so I am putting those values in the array. This time single element values are received in code ignitor but that values do not pass in the array that is shown some error. Empty Alert How can I solve the problem.

```
  $uname = $this->input->post('name');
        $umobile = $this->input->post('mobile');
        $udob = $this->input->post('dob');
        $ugender = $this->input->post('gender');
        $uage = $this->input->post('age');
//        $uphoto = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
//        $sphoto = $_FILES['sphoto']['name'];
        $uphoto = "Data";
        $sphoto = "Testing";
        $uanuvacery = $this->input->post('anuvacery');
        $sname = $this->input->post('sname');
        $sshopnumber = $this->input->post('shopnumber');
        $sgst = $this->input->post('sgst');
        $deal = $this->input->post('deal');
        $address = $this->input->post('address');
        $dist = $this->input->post('dist');
        $mturn = $this->input->post('mturn');

        $data = array(
            'uid' => '00',
            'uname' => $uname,
            'umobile' => $umobile,
            'udob' => $udob,
            'ugen' => $ugender,
            'uprofile' => $uphoto,
            'uanu' => $uanuvacery,
            'sname' => $sname,
            'sphone' => $sshopnumber,
            'sgst' => $sgst,
            'sdtype' => $deal,
            'sphoto' => $sphoto,
            'sturn' => $mturn,
            'district' => $dist,
            'uaddress' => $address,
            'uage' => $uage
        );
```

Comment: Guys, I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to print an values using `printr($data);`

That is wrong printing method

```
print_r($data);


exit();
```

This is the correct printing method.